# How do I calculate the disk read speed(in MB/s) in a for loop with fgets

Tags: c, windows

I have the following function

```
for(i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    fgets(i[*compare], 36, fp);
```

It populates the "pointer to an array of X chars of an array of X chars with the string from the file pointer stream `fp`. The variable `lines` is the number of lines the file has(precomputed).

I wish to calculate the reading speed of the `fgets` operation. However I am unsure of how to do this, nor the "formula"

Comment: Ostensibly it seems pretty straightforward. You want to find out how many Megabytes (translated from bytes) per second. You can access how long the loop takes and how many bytes you're reading. Where are you having issues?

Comment: I guess, I do not know the formula for this?

Comment: `(bytes_read / 1000000) / time_taken`?

Comment: You could calculate on an average case how fast your os can read a file.  The abstraction on top of the hardware and load will prevent and accurate measure of drive speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `clock_gettime` to obtain some time, and wrap it around fgets. Then appropriately subtract `a` from `b` and you have the time it took to execute fgets (and one clock_gettime call).

```
#include <time.h>
struct timespec a, b;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &a);
fgets(...)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &b);
```

36 chars is not a lot, so it'll be over faster than can be noticably measured. (But then again I hear Linus's words (about git), "well maybe on Windows maybe you can [measure it]"…) Anyhow, you then now that (at most) this many chars were transferred in the found delta time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and just to clarify, my file has over 2 million lines, so while the lines will be read faster than 1 line/s it will take long overall.

Comment: Sorry to say, but it appears CLOCK_MONOTONIC is a unix macro. It is also a fail on my part for not mentioning I am using MinGW(w64) under Windows.

Comment: You can attempt to use CLOCK_REALTIME also. (Or any other clock, but make sure it's synchronized to the wall clock and is preferably in seconds :)